# Display submission history of a node?

Tags: views

Use case: This content type offers an Approval Status with three radion button options, Submitted, Approve, and Reject.

A node from this content type can go through all three in its lifetime.

And that "history" should be displayed at the bottom of  the page.

How do I do this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You will need to make sure that the content type creates a new version with every edit. Then, you should be able to make a Views block that shows node versions and the status field.

Comment: I'm familiar with showing revision via Views...sort of.. but can I get it specific to the select items as shown in the screen capture?

Comment: Do you just want the last date for each state, or a full "history"?

Comment: For now, just the last date for each state.